# How do you hold down keys using the "Keyboard" module in python?

Tags: python, keyboard

I am creating a racing game AI, and am trying to get it to hold down keys rather than it just tapping the keys on the keyboard really fast, such as holding down "w" to accelerate rather than just feather tapping it. Is there any way to make the keyboard module in python press and hold down a key until a certain input is pressed(such as "del")?
The Keyboard module:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/keyboard-module-in-python/

This is what I have tried, but it just presses the button once, then waits until I press 'del' to end the program, and finish.

```
keyboard.press('w')
keyboard.wait('del')
keyboard.release('w')
```

Comment: Can you use other than `keyboard` module?

Comment: Why not just have the keypress set a var, and as long as the var is True your program acts as if the key is pressed? Certainly a much better system than spamming keycodes.

Comment: Also, that wait is probably blocking. Keyboard is threaded, but not every key gets it's own thread. Your code basically says "press and hold w, never-mind just wait for 'del'". I'd be willing to bet if you got rid of the last 2 lines it would work fine, you just won't be able to stop. However, you then solve the stop problem without breaking the start problem.

Comment: I deleted my answer. You have far too many questions. If you are this mystified by setting a boolean and using a game loop, I would suggest taking a huge step back and gather a greater understanding of the language, games and what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the keyboard module is not as good of a choice to *hold* the key down as @Alderven mentioned, but it is great for detecting key presses instead if that helps your code. I would recommend using pyautogui. For example:

```
import pyautogui
import time

def accelerate():
    pyautogui.keyDown('w') #holds the key down
    time.sleep(5) #could be replaced with detecting an input
    pyautogui.keyUp('w') #releases the key
    return 0
```

**Note:** When you run the program, in the shell, there will not be a bunch of w's being typed as you'd expect, like this: wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww. Instead, at least for me, only one w was pressed. I don't know why this occurs, although I can tell you that the key w is being pressed and this is NOT an error. I know this because I tried playing a game that involved pressing the key w (just an online web browser racing game), and the code worked. If you truly wanted the output "wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww", then you can just use pyautogui's write() function:

```
pyautogui.write("wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww")
```

and there you go. Since you were referring to a racing game that doesn't involve getting a string of w's, this probably doesn't apply to your code.

If you want to wait for a certain input instead of holding down the key for a certain amount of time like I did, you could instead replace this:

```
time.sleep(5)
```

with this:

```
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('del')
    break
```

You would have to import the keyboard module for that to work, since pyautogui cannot detect key presses.

Pynput is another great choice of module besides pyautogui, and there are a lot of other great Stack Overflow posts about pyautogui and pynput, so if this solution doesn't work, you should check those out if you haven't already. It would also help if you clarified about the context of the code, as mentioned by @OysterShucker. If it is a racing game AI, why does it need the user to input the del key so the AI knows when to release the w key, and why not automate it? Those are questions that I would recommend answering.